# Task Manager crashes after enabling SVM

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, task-manager

I have Windows 10 Pro, build 19042.746; AMD Ryzen 5 2600; MSI B450M-A PRO MAX.

I installed WSL2 (Ubuntu) and enabled virtualization (SVM) in BIOS, and the WSL works fine.

But then I noticed that Task Manager isn't working. When I open the Performance tab, it freezes and after I click again (anywhere in the window) the window shrinks so only its toolbar (the part where the name and maximize and close buttons are) is visible. All other tabs work fine.

I tried disabling SVM, which resolved the issue, but now I can't use WSL.

Is there a way to solve this? I wouldn't mind this if there was an alternative to the task manager's performance view, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but when I searched Google for `lock ups after enabling virtualization`, there were a lot of different suggestions.  I know your issue isn't *quite* a lock-up, but it could still be indicative of a similar problem.  Hopefully it's not a hardware issue.  Have you (a) updated the BIOS, (b) disabled any advanced Windows security features such as *Device Security* -> *Core Isolation*, *Ransomware Protection* -> *Controlled Folder Access* (I know this one caused WSL issues for me), Shadow Defender (if installed), etc?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thx for an answer.
Well, I haven't updated the bios yet as I was looking at it as a Windows problem, not bios one. And I couldn't find the setting. It says there *Standard hardware security not supported.*, and *Memory integrity* setting. Btw. I am using the F-Secure antivirus instead of Windows Defender.
It hopefully isn't a hardware issue as the computer is just half a year old. Otherwise, everything I can think of works completely fine, so it may be just a software issue.